# Maximum number of points in unit cube

Tags: geometry

What is the maximum number of points that can be within a unit cube (no points on cube vertices, faces, or edges) such that no two points are within 1 of each other?

I'm asking because I'm creating a grid-based acceleration structure for a program I'm writing, and I need to know how much memory to give each "cube".

Comment: This problem appears to translate pretty trivially to sphere packing in 3d space (given your minimum radius between points). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture; it seems a efficient method would have your points in the cannonball stack arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the maximum is six points. An example of six such points plus the distances between them is shown below:

a= (0.001953125,0.001953125,0.5)
b= (0.875,0.001953125,0.001953125)
c= (0.001953125,0.875,0.001953125)
d= (0.998046875,0.998046875,0.5)
e= (0.125,0.998046875,0.998046875)
f= (0.998046875,0.125,0.998046875)
ab= 1.00511767253617
ac= 1.00511767253617
ad= 1.40868929064508
ae= 1.12044365406458
af= 1.12044365406458
ba= 1.00511767253617
bc= 1.23467473121245
bd= 1.12044365406458
be= 1.59590272810661
bf= 1.01117942309147
ca= 1.00511767253617
cb= 1.23467473121245
cd= 1.12044365406458
ce= 1.01117942309147
cf= 1.59590272810661
da= 1.40868929064508
db= 1.12044365406458
dc= 1.12044365406458
de= 1.00511767253617
df= 1.00511767253617
ea= 1.12044365406458
eb= 1.59590272810661
ec= 1.01117942309147
ed= 1.00511767253617
ef= 1.23467473121245
fa= 1.12044365406458
fb= 1.01117942309147
fc= 1.59590272810661
fd= 1.00511767253617
fe= 1.23467473121245

As an explanation: I used the back of an envelope to develop the principle, then an excel spreadsheet to produce the numbers. For principle: if you start with points a=(0,0,0),b=(1,0,0),c=(0,1,0) and d=(1,1,1),e=(1,0,1), f=(0,1,1) then they are all exactly 1 unit apart and all on the vertices, so fail on all requirements. Now push the points a and d along the z axis (away from the vertices) by distance p. Then push points b,c, along the x or y axis (so they move closer to a) by distance p^3, (similarly with points e and f so they move closer to point d). Finally move each point distance p^9 along each axis as required to move it away from the edge it is on. The points will all be inside the cube so meet the first specification. I can't do Latex, so it is hard to explain why the distances are always greater than 1, but in principle, each distance_squared will be of the form 1+u*p^m-v*p^n(+/-)other terms in p to higher powers. By choosing p, p^3 and p^9 it is always the case that the index m is smaller than the index n, so for a sufficiently small p, the positive term u*p^m will always be greater than the largest negative term v*p^n (and any other -ve terms) so the length^2 will be greater than 1. In practice it works for p in the range (0+..0.52+) and I chose 0.5 because it produced a nice symmetry. The solution would probably also work for increments p, p^(2+delta), and maybe p^(4+3*delta), fore any delta > 0 but I haven't checked that. As to my belief that 6 is the maximum, that is just a guess (it is definitely less than 8) so unless someone can find a solution with 7 points...

Comment: Mathematica? :-) More generally, how did you get to this answer?

Comment: See edited bit in the answer - I need to learn Latex.